# mod_wsgi - mod_wsgi-express error AH00526: Syntax error on line 16

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-14.04

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234782/mod-wsgi-mod-wsgi-express-error-more-than-one-mpm-loaded/26549980#26549980) is related with my question.

Actually I use the Apacha Version over Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bits:
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38

When I type command mod_wsgi-express start-server to check if it runs. It seems not running and I have an error:

```
root@website:/home/website# mod_wsgi-express start-server
Server URL        : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root       : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0
Server Conf       : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf
Error Log File    : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/error_log
AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf:
Error:\tApache has not been designed to serve pages while\n\trunning as root.  There are known race conditions that\n\twill allow any local user to read any file on the system.\n\tIf you still desire to serve pages as root then\n\tadd -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE to the CFLAGS env variable\n\tand then rebuild the server.\n\tIt is strongly suggested that you instead modify the User\n\tdirective in your httpd.conf file to list a non-root\n\tuser.\n
```

I have the same problem during installation to [doom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234782/mod-wsgi-mod-wsgi-express-error-more-than-one-mpm-loaded/26549980#26549980). Any suggest is welcome!

**More Information:**

Modules used in Apache:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

Python Version:

```
>>> print (sys.version) 
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear: don't run as root. Why are you doing that anyway? You should never actually be logged in as root.

Comment: Yes, I note later! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to spin up a TurboGears python application. I was finally able to get it started by executing the start-server command with the user option included. I set the user option equal to the user running apache. In my case the user is "apache". See below.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mod_wsgi-express start-server --user=apache <path_to_my_wsgi_file>
```